# Custom Zendesk Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using Zendesk lately, And really got annoyed by their keyboard shortcuts. I've tried setting up my own shortcuts using a chrome extension [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) with no luck.

Here's the jQuery code I'm using :

```
$(".ember-view.solved.status._tooltip")[0].click()
```

Screenshots of the view I'm trying to click on :

[image]

It's code :

[image]

The click event is firing, But not doing the desired action (Marking ticket as solved).
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without access to your view. Just saying.. Note: Try  `$(".ember-view.solved.status._tooltip").trigger('click')` instead of your code. Is it working?

Comment: Unfortunately not, It doesn't work. I've updated the question with screenshots.

Comment: Try to find the code the handle the click event in the code and see how the delegation goes (if is after `click`). It's not an easy way, you need to dig deep in the code.

Comment: Can you mention any useful references to follow ?

Comment: There are some question in SO that you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10639089/863110, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11008047/863110, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10262902/863110. Generally I searched `how to check which function called from specific click button` in Google.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this done, Can you make a trial account on their site and check it please ? Thanks.

Comment: When I will have spare time